# how to unit test SQL DB connected methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, backend, sqlconnection

I have to test the method that including below:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Execute(query, sqlParams, commandTimeout: commandTimeout);

        return success;
    }

    //...
```

Actually I don't want to connect the real DB. Method takes connectionString as string parameter. How can I test it?
I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting library and Moq library.
Language is C#, .NET

Comment: There are a few methods used in practice: (1) abstract away SqlConnection, (2) abstract away the whole DB layer, or (3) use a separate "unit test database".

Comment: Generally one might create an injectable abstraction which wraps the `SqlConnection` and other database dependencies.  Then you can inject a mock for those dependencies and validate that the mock was invoked.  But in this case there isn't any real logic in this code to be meaningfully tested, and the implementation of the abstraction would essentially just repeat what's implemented here, adding no real value.  Can you clarify what's being tested and validated here?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I want to test if method correctly executing query and return success.

Comment: And why don't you want to connect to the real DB? I guess by "real DB" you mean the development DB, not the staging or production DB, right?

Comment: Because of tight coupling to implementation concerns, the only way to test this code would be connecting to an actual database which would make this an integration test. There is no way to "unit test" this code in isolation without undesired behvaior

Comment: The approach we used to minimize the number of modifications to our development DB through automated tests was to set up a transaction scope in `<TestInitialize()>` and roll back all changes in `<TestCleanup()>`. It's not ideal, but it's a lot less work than mocking away all DB operations. In situations where this is not possible, we use a designated unit-test DB (created on the fly) or manually undo all unit-test modifications during initialization and clean-up.

Comment: For unit testing you need to mock , for that write an interface and do the implementation(one real and other unit test mock) of the same

Comment: Thank for all ideas! I created an .mdf file and a table. Now my test methods using it and not connecting to dev or prod DB.